# get the max heap size of a node.js application

Tags: node.js, heap-memory

Now I am using node.js in paas platform. And the container has memory limit. Now I want to get the maximum of the heap size of node.js application. I know that use the parameter "--max-old-space-size", I can set the max heap size, but I want to know how to get the default value of "--max-old-space-size". For example, if the container's memory is 512m , so the maximum of node.js heap size can not be greater than it. How can I get the value?

Comment: i used this once https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch
`memwatch.on('stats', function(stats) { ... });` also @alex-rokabilis seems right

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try the `v8` module, it is documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html

I believe `getHeapStatistics()` function will give you everything you need

Comment: I install node.js v0.12.7 and require('v8'), when try to run the program and it shows "Cannot find module 'v8'". Then I install node.js v5.0.0 and it works. How can I make it work in v0.12.7?

Comment: @qibobo you basically can't. This function was added on v1.0.0

Comment: This answer is far better than running `process.memoryUsage`.

Comment: @qibobo this answer should be marked correct imo. To be precise, we can do `v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size / 1024 / 1024` (in GB) to get that max allowed.

Comment: @shriek `/ 1024 / 1024` will give you MB, not GB

Comment: Just to reframe the steps : Open Nodejs and then use this formula as suggested to get in GB :
(v8.getHeapStatistics().total_available_size / 1024 /1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)

Comment: I don't believe this is the correct answer. The heap consists of several parts, where the "old space" is only one of them. I don't have proof, but I think that `total_available_size !=  --max-old-space-size`, more specifically it might be that `total_available_size > --max-old-space-size`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `process.memoryUsage` https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage

Comment: This does not tell you the maximum heap size, it tells you the current heap size and how much of the heap you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. V8 does not expose this information via its API.

The information available via `node:v8` library **does not** include the "maximum old space size", contrary to the accepted answer. The information returned from `getHeapStatistics()` only contain `total_heap_size`.

There is a chance that `getHeapSpaceStatistics()` (notice the "`Space`" in the method name) might contain the required information, but from my understanding it's also only runtime information, and the `space_available_size` might not reflect the `max-old-space-size` implicit setting.

There is [an issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39107) in the Node repository to add a simple explanation about the general heap size to docs, but it's still unresolved.

I was able to find the [part of the V8 source code](https://github.dev/nodejs/node/blob/00a428eedd8bbed0da77416675db87dda7d473cd/deps/v8/src/heap/heap.cc#L4837-L4864) that calculates the default, but it was hard for me to understand it and explain in simpler pseudocode. Maybe somebody will find it helpful:

```cpp
  // Initialize max_old_generation_size_ and max_global_memory_.
  {
    size_t max_old_generation_size = 700ul * (kSystemPointerSize / 4) * MB;
    if (constraints.max_old_generation_size_in_bytes() > 0) {
      max_old_generation_size = constraints.max_old_generation_size_in_bytes();
    }
    if (v8_flags.max_old_space_size > 0) {
      max_old_generation_size =
          static_cast<size_t>(v8_flags.max_old_space_size) * MB;
    } else if (v8_flags.max_heap_size > 0) {
      size_t max_heap_size = static_cast<size_t>(v8_flags.max_heap_size) * MB;
      size_t young_generation_size =
          YoungGenerationSizeFromSemiSpaceSize(max_semi_space_size_);
      max_old_generation_size = max_heap_size > young_generation_size
                                    ? max_heap_size - young_generation_size
                                    : 0;
    }
    max_old_generation_size =
        std::max(max_old_generation_size, MinOldGenerationSize());
    max_old_generation_size = std::min(max_old_generation_size,
                                       AllocatorLimitOnMaxOldGenerationSize());
    max_old_generation_size =
        RoundDown<Page::kPageSize>(max_old_generation_size);

    max_global_memory_size_ =
        GlobalMemorySizeFromV8Size(max_old_generation_size);
    set_max_old_generation_size(max_old_generation_size);
  }
```